How do I capture apt-get 'Note, selecting'
Command apt-get install libgnutls30 prints "Note, selecting libgnutls30t64 instead of libgnutls30" to console.
If "stdout" and "stderr" are redirected to files, it appears in neither. strace seems to indicate it redirects to /dev/null in this case.
Is there a way to capture this message to a file?

You could see what's actually installed by looking at the files in /var/log/apt/.

It looks like the apt family write informational messages to /dev/tty when output is a TTY device, and to /dev/null otherwise. The same "trick" using the script program, described here for apt-file:

How to redirect the output of apt-file update into a file?

appears to work for apt as well, ex.
$ script -c 'sudo apt-get install --dry-run libgnutls30' -O apt.log
Script started, output log file is 'apt.log'.
[sudo] password for steeldriver: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'libgnutls30t64' instead of 'libgnutls30'
libgnutls30t64 is already the newest version (3.8.3-1.1ubuntu3.1).
libgnutls30t64 set to manually installed.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 11 not upgraded.
Script done.

then
$ cat apt.log
Script started on 2024-08-22 13:01:25-04:00 [COMMAND="sudo apt-get install --dry-run libgnutls30" TERM="xterm-256color" TTY="/dev/pts/2" COLUMNS="172" LINES="38"]
[sudo] password for steeldriver: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'libgnutls30t64' instead of 'libgnutls30'
libgnutls30t64 is already the newest version (3.8.3-1.1ubuntu3.1).
libgnutls30t64 set to manually installed.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 11 not upgraded.

Script done on 2024-08-22 13:01:29-04:00 [COMMAND_EXIT_CODE="0"]

